# Comparing variable string with a value cause a warning ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

In my ruby 2.2.3 code I have a method in a class as follow

```
def partner?
  auth_token.application.kind == 'partner'
end
```

Basically auth_token.application.kind will return a string but this function cause this:

```
Comparable#== will no more rescue exceptions of #<=> in the next release.
```

I am curious about this and I tried this instead

```
def partner?
  'partner' == auth_token.application.kind
end
```

Then the warning is disappeared. Can anyone explain me the different between comparing string with variable on the left and right side of the expression above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess in the first case auth_token.application.kind is returning an object that is not a standard Ruby String, and it is therefore executing that object's == method (which includes code to output the warning you see).

In the second case it is executing the 'partner' string's == method, which is just the standard Ruby String == method which does not generate this warning.

Note that in Ruby == is a method, if you were to write your example this way the reason for the difference would probably seem more clear:

```
auth_token.application.kind.==('partner')

'partner'.==(auth_token.application.kind)
```

Comment: More specifically, `kind` includes `Comparable` and its `<=>` method is raising an error. It should return `nil` instead if the objects are not comparable as specified in the documentation.